# Add mysql table functionality

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in SQL. I have created 3 tables in my database : "DOCTORID", "PATIENTS", "VISITS". For simplicity purposes, I have only a one-to-many relationship btw these tables : One doctor has many patients and one patient can have many visits... in my table "VISITS".

How can I have a link to each patient and add or create a new visit? Each visit will have some fields like for example: chief complaint, vital signs. I need my visits to have automatically todays date and hour. I would like to add new visits and verify or read past visits.

The patient id is $id in my 'patients' table.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.atlasindia.com/sql.htm

Comment: This reads more like a specification and less like a question.  StackOverflow is aimed towards specific questions, not teaching people languages.  In other words, as Diego implied, it sounds like you need to learn SQL a bit better.

Comment: You may be right. Like I said, I am a beginner learning by trial and error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an overview, visits would contain:

Visit_ID, Patient_ID, Doctor_ID, chief_complaint, vital_signs, timestamp

Comment: Well no, in TNF there would be no Doctor_ID field.

Comment: but you'll need to record which visit + patient saw which doctor. You could do a visit table, with visit_ID, patient_id and doctor_id, and then a visit_info table with visit_id, chief_complaint, vital_signs, timestamp

Comment: It depends how you read the question. Nut if every patient is always seen by the same doctor then no, you do not.